# Get list of numbers then return the numbers in the list that are increasing

Tags: python

So I have to create a function that takes a list of numbers than returns the one in the list that are in increasing order, and it has to increase by 2. So for example: `[5, 2, 1, 3, 4]` would return `[1, 3, 4]` since the last 3 are in increasing order.

So far I have this:

```
def numIncreasing1(L):

a = []

for i in L:
    if i+2 == L[i+1]:
        a = a.append(L[i])
return a
```

Although this would give me an index out of range error, how would I go upon creating this function?

Comment: What would be the output for `[5, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4]`?

Comment: It would be [1, 3] since those are the first list of numbers that are increasing by 2. Sorry forgot to mention it has to increase by 2.